# Bind model to DLL function

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a win forms application that I'm rewriting to use WPF and MVVM pattern.
It uses a DLL written in C++ to expose a couple of functions that I will need to bind my model to in the WPF application.

For example I have this function from the DLL.

```
// The user supplied function will be called whenever a frame of data arrives.
SetDataHandlerFunc(void (*MyFunction)(sFrameOfData* pFrameOfData));
```

I've got a wrapper dll that looks like this:

```
public delegate void HandlerFunction(IntPtr frameData);

[DllImport("lib\\SDK.dll")]
public extern static int SetDataHandlerFunc(HandlerFunction function);
```

to let me later use it in my forms application like this:

```
private HandlerFunction myFunction;
myFunction = new HandlerFunction(threadFunction);

private void threadFunction(IntPtr FrameData)
{
    sFrameOfData frame = (sFrameOfData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(FrameData, typeof(sFrameOfData));
}
```

But I can't really figure out how to translate this to MVVM and the WPF data binding. 
I think that I'm probably looking at using a ObjectDataProvider to bind to a method.

I will need to grab some parameters from the frame data (returned as a sFrameOfData object above) and show them in the GUI and have them update as the data changes.

Any ideas on how to implement something like this?

Comment: Can you not just create properties for those parameters on your view model, and when threadfunction is called (I presume this is called from the dll to update the framedata when required), update those properties (which should already be raising notification of change)?  Thus updating the bound xaml controls?

Comment: Those controls being bound so aforementioned properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't actually bind to the method.
In your view model have the properties that represent the paramters you are interested in and bind to those.

So in your threadFunction get back your sFrameOfData object, and then set the values of the properties on your viewmodel.
Make sure you implement INotifyPropertyChanged to raise the property changed event to the view, on which you have the controls that bind to the properties on your viewmodel.